# Create array based on matrix and vector

Tags: r

I have a matrix called A:

```
A=matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow=2,ncol=2)
```

I then want to obtain an array, which is based on a vector, say `a=c(1,0.5,2)`, in the following way:

1A=matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow=2,ncol=2)

0.5A=matrix(c(0.5,1,1.5,2),nrow=2,ncol=2)

2A=matrix(c(2,4,6,8),nrow=2,ncol=2)

So I want matrix 1A in the first dimension of the array, 0.5A in the second dimension of the array and finally 2A in the third dimension of the array.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `simplify = 'array'` and `sapply`

```
sapply(c(1,0.5,2),'*',A,simplify='array')
# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    4
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  0.5  1.5
# [2,]  1.0  2.0
# 
# , , 3
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    6
# [2,]    4    8
```

Or `kronecker` to obtain the kronecker product of two arrays

```
kronecker(array(c(1,0.5,2),c(1,1,3)),A)
# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    4
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  0.5  1.5
# [2,]  1.0  2.0
# 
# , , 3
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    6
# [2,]    4    8
```

Comment: @Ku-trala  `kronecker` is an `s4` method so method dispatch and any copying might take time. `sapply` calls `simplify2array` which is notorious for being "slow". The tradeoff between method dispatch and simplify2array speeds will depend on the size of the inputs and result.